# loopback component push save push model into database

Tags: strongloop

is there any way to save the Models which extends Push (Push as base) . Like I want to save the push model into database after I have sent a push notification.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Push+notifications#Pushnotifications-Createapushmodel? Can you describe your scenario a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question right, you need to save the notification message itself. Seems like it is not a Push model instance you may be interested in, but Notification. Here is what documentation says ([same link](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Push+notifications#Pushnotifications-Architecture) as provided by @superkhau):

> Notification - model to capture notification messages and persist scheduled notifications.

It means that if you are not scheduling notifications (which is not available yet anyway), but sending them via *PushManager.notifyByQuery* or *PushManager.notifyById*, the Notification will not be persisted. So what I would try to do is put this logic into a custom method and do two operations, e.g.:

```
Notification.create(notificationData, function(err, createdNotification) {
  PushManager.notifyById(someId, createdNotification, ...)
  ...
}
```

What I'm really not sure yet about is what is the plan of doing scheduling of notifications and whether such approach will conflict with it somehow.